# How to animate menu items on Toolbar

Tags: android, material-design, android-animation, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

Can anyone please guide me on how this animation [here](https://developer.android.com/design/material/videos/ContactsAnim.mp4) could be done? I know that the Logo and Text is done through Shared Elements but how about the other views?

How was the toolbar icons and back button animated? and how was the incoming list translate to top?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @krishankTripathi I had a quick look on the github link. I don't understand how handling scrolls or bottomsheets would solve my question. My question refers to animating individual views on activity start or when a fragment is added.

Answer (score 0):

Just for animation

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon"
    android:title="@string/title"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.ImageView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

and call it like

```
 val icon: ImageView  = menu!!.getItem(0).actionView as ImageView
```

then as an image view you can give it an animation
the problem is that, with this you loose the padding of the Menu item